# Optimizing a function that seems to execute really slowly when there are a lot of usernames in the file

Tags: c, optimization, file-handling

I wrote a small program, about 10,500 lines and everything works perfectly.

It is a Math game, which has is login and sign-up process and all data is stored on the user's computer in multiple text files. It has support for multiple users.

I wrote a function which allows the user to search for another user in the database, and if the username is not found the program attempts to find the user name in the file which closely resemble the one that was entered and provide suggestions.

However, this function seems to execute  really slowly when there are a lot of usernames in the file.

How I can optimize it?

```
// Function to generate suggestions
void Suggestions (char passed[])
{
    /**
        In the case that the administrator makes an error while searching for a user,
        tghe program attempts to determine the username in the database which closest
        matches the username that wa entered
    */

    // Vaiables
    char sname[MAX], record[MAX];
    int w, x, y, z;
    char abs = 'N', f = 'N';
    int len = 0, temp = 0;

    // Sets them all to 0
    w = x = y = z = 0

    taken user[MAX];

    // Attempts to open file
    ptrRead = fopen("UserNames.smq", "r");

    if(ptrRead == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nThe file was not found ...\n\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // Copies the incorrect username passed to the function
        strcpy(sname, passed);

        // Encrypts the passed name 
        for(x = 0; x < strlen(passed); x++)
        {
            sname[x] += key;
        }

        // Sets x to 0
        x = 0;

        // Reads all of file with the usernames 
        while(!feof(ptrRead))
        {
            fgets(record, MAX - 1, ptrRead);

            // Compares the strings
            if(strcmp(record, sname) == 0)
            {
                // Sets found to yes
                f = 'Y';

                // Breaks our of loop
                break;
            }
            // End if
        }
        // End while


        if(f == 'N')
        {
            // Rewinds the file pointer
            rewind(ptrRead);

            // Reads the data of the file and calculate various contents
            while(!feof(ptrRead))
            {
                // Sets temp to 0
                temp = 0;

                // Gets the username
                fgets(record, MAX - 1, ptrRead);

                // Copes the information
                strcpy(user[x].userName, record);

                // Calculate the length
                len = strlen(user[x].userName) - strlen(sname);

                // Determines if the name is valid for testing
                if(len == -2 || len == -1 || len == 0 || len == 1 || len == 2)
                {
                    /**
                        This if statement limits the number of work trhe program does by eliminating
                        the usernames with a difference in string length grater than 2 or less than - 2
                    */

                    // Counts the number of letters common in a sequence
                    for(w = 0; w < strlen(user[x].userName); w++)
                    {
                        /**
                            It does not matter which string length the for-loops runs for because
                            when the average is calculated, the same result appears both ways
                        */

                        // Compares both letters
                        if(user[x].userName[w] == sname[w])
                        {
                            /**
                                If both letters at the current index are the same, then temp will be
                                increased by the value 1. If not, then temo will not increase. This gets
                                the number of letter the two names have in common in a sequence.
                            */

                            temp++;
                        }
                        // End if
                    }
                    /* End for */

                    // Calculates the average letters in common
                    user[x].lettersInCommom = (float) temp / ((strlen(user[x].userName) + strlen(sname)) / 2) * 100.0;

                    // Sets temp to 0
                    temp = 0;

                    // Calculates the number of letters the have in common
                    for(y = 0; y < strlen(sname); y++)
                    {
                        /*
                            Runs the loop until the string length of the incorrect username - Just for fun
                        */
                        for(w = 0; w < strlen(user[x].userName) ; w++)
                        {
                            /**
                                This for loop runs for the entire string lenght of the username in the file
                            */

                            // Compares the letters
                            if(user[x].userName[w] == sname[y])
                            {
                                /**
                                    Compares the characters at the current index. If they are the same,
                                    then temp increase by 1. The purpose of these nested loops is to
                                    check the number of letters the two name have in common in general,
                                    and not just in a sequence.
                                */
                                temp++;  // Increments temp
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Calculates the average letters in common in general
                    if(strlen(user[x].userName) > strlen(sname))
                    {
                        user[x].lettersInGeneral = (float) temp / (float) strlen(sname)  * 100.0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user[x].lettersInGeneral = (float) temp / (float) strlen(user[x].userName)  * 100.0;
                    }

                    // Sets temp to 0
                    temp = 0;

                    // Checks if both names begins with the same letter
                    if(sname[0] == user[x].userName[0])
                    {
                        user[x].beginsWithFirst = 100.0;   // Assign 100
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user[x].beginsWithFirst = 0.0;      // Assign 0
                    }

                    // Checks if the names ends with the same letter
                    if(sname[strlen(sname) - 1] == user[x].userName[strlen(user[x].userName) -1])
                    {
                        user[x].endsWithLast = 100.0;       // Assign 100
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user[x].endsWithLast = 0.0;         // Assign 0
                    }
                }

                /**
                    Calculates the rank. The rank is an overall percentage that represents the average similarity
                    that the username in the file has with the incorrect username entered. Similar usernames
                    normally have a rank of over 70%
                */

                user[x].rank = (user[x].lettersInCommom + user[x].lettersInGeneral + user[x].beginsWithFirst + user[x].endsWithLast) / 4.0;

                // Increments x
                x++;
            }

            // Closes the file
            fclose(ptrRead);

            // Sets temp to 0
            temp = 0;

            for(z = 0; z < x; z++)
            {
                /*
                    Runs  until the number of usernames in the file is reached
                */
                if(user[z].rank > 70.00 && user[z].rank < 200.00)
                {
                    // Increments temp by 1 if conditon is met
                    temp++;
                }
            }

            if(temp > 0)
            {
                temp = 0;  // Resets temp

                /*
                    This is done to determine whether or not to print the contents in this if statement.
                    If no suggestion were found then printing "Did you mean" would be a waste of processing.
                */

                // Clears the screen
                system("cls");

                printf("\n\t\t\t\tOoops!");
                printf("\n\t\t\t*********************\n\n");
                printf("\nLooks like you made an error in your search. ");

                printf("Did you mean: \n\n");

                // For all the usernames
                for(z = 0; z < x; z++)
                {
                    // Checks the rank
                    if(user[z].rank > 70.00 && user[z].rank < 200.00)
                    {
                        /* Increments temp */
                        temp++;

                        for(w = 0; w < strlen(user[z].userName); w++)
                        {
                            // Decrypts the name
                            user[z].userName[w] -= key);
                        }

                        if(key > 2)
                        {
                            /**
                                This removes a weird looking character that always shows at the end
                                of the username when the key is greater than 2.
                            */

                            user[z].userName[strlen(user[z].userName) - 1] = '\0';
                        }

                        // Prints decrypted user name as is
                        printf("\n(%d)\t%s", temp, user[z].userName);
                    }
                }

                // Allows the admin to search again
                ViewSingleUser();
            }
            else
            {
                // Prints error
                printf("\n\nWe were unable to detect any possible matches ...");
            }
        }
    }
}
// Function ends here
```

Comment: Did you consider publishing your code as free software e.g. on http://github.com/ ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I tried searching for it, but it didn't show up.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, I actually made a github account the other day. But I'm no expert at C programming, so I don't think I'd have much use there.

Comment: Publishing a beginner's code (e.g. on `github` under some open source license) gives others the ability to look into it and give feedback on it (and you won't get any feedback without showing the *entire* source code).

Comment: Just a tip: strlen () takes O (n) time when the string has length n. A loop: for (i = 0; i < strlen (s); ++i) ... takes O (n^2) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### general hints

I would consider (hoping that you are using Linux and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), which is an excellent developer environment):

- read a good [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) (that is, spend at least a week reading it); be aware of good [container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_%28abstract_data_type%29) algorithms like [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and [self-balancing binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree). BTW, if you coded in C++11 or C++14 (not C99 or C11) or in Ocaml, its standard library provides them (e.g. C++ [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) like [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), etc.. or Ocaml [standard library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/stdlib.html) modules like [Set](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.html) or [Hashtbl](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html), etc...). Have a good estimate of [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of your functions.
- enable all warnings and debug info in your code (so compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`); improve your code till you get no warnings
- test your program and have some test suite
- use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
- profile your code, e.g. by compiling it with `gcc -pg -Wall -g` then using [gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/); find out the functions consuming most of the CPU time and focus on improving and rewriting them
- consider perhaps using some relational database, e.g. read some [SQL tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/) and use [sqlite](http://sqlite.org).
- consider using some [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to compare similarity of strings
- study the source code of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects similar to yours.

---

### about your code

<sup>(we don't know how your `Suggestion` function is called and what it should really do)</sup>

Notice that your nested loops look suspicious.

Use `perror` or `strerror(errno)` on failure of `fopen` so code:

```
ptrRead = fopen("UserNames.smq", "r");

if(ptrRead == NULL) {
    perror("UserNames.smq");
    return; // or perhaps exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The `f` variable should be a `bool f = false;` since it is a boolean flag.

You don't modify `sname` after its initialization from `passed`, so why don't you declare `void Suggestions (const char* passed)` and use `passed` everywhere instead of `sname`? No need to copy the unmodified `passed` string to `sname` (which you don't modify neither)...

You don't handle or avoid [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). In particular, if the `sname` happens to be a very long string (wider than your `MAX`...) you have the dreaded [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

BTW, loops like `for(y = 0; y < strlen(sname); y++)` are really inefficient. You are computing the string length at every iteration; better memoize it and compute the string length once:

```
size_t snlen = strlen(sname);
for (y=0; y<snlen; y++)
```

<sup>(some compilers might be able to do such an optimization, but you should not take it as granted)</sup>

Also, use more systematically pointers to `char`, e.g. replace

```
for(w = 0; w < strlen(user[z].userName); w++)
                {
                    // Decrypts the name
                    user[z].userName[w] -= key);
                }
```

with

```
for (char*pc = user[z].userName; *pc; pc++)
  *pc -= key;
```

Such a loop is shorter to write and use character pointers, don't compute the `strlen` at every iteration, and use the fact that strings are terminated by a zero byte.

Of course, be aware that your [encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) is really poor; if you need some, use an existing encryption library or function (see [crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) and [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) ...)